# Стандартный алгоритм поиска и функции поиска строкового класса

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

```
std::find_first_of
```

Ищет в множестве элементов первое вхождение любого элемента другого множества, а

```
std::find
```

Находит в одном диапазоне  первый элемент, удовлетворяющий определённым условиям.
Понятно  чем отличаются эти алгоритмы поиска.

Но чем отличаются  `std::string::find`  и  `std::string::find_first_of`?   Если  нетрудно приведите пример, где  одна функция предпочтительней другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Говорить о *предпочтительности* совершенно разных функций как-то странно. Где предпочтительнее, например, искать квадратный корень, а где - логарифм? :)

`find` ищет подстроку, а `find_first_of` - любой символ из переданной строки.

Грубо говоря, для строки `"abracadabra"` и подстроки `"cad"` `find` вернет 4, а `find_first_of` - 0 (первая же буква `a` есть в `"cad"`).